# Identifying and Copying only those files which has not been read in SSIS in last iteration

Tags: ssis

I have a location where, log files are dumped from Source team every hour. So, 24 files for 24 hours. I have created a SSIS Package to read the data from the location every 1 day.
Issue is, I end up reading all the files currently present there, no matter I had already read some files 1 day back.

Eg: On 23 Feb, 8am I ran the package which read all files till that time. On 24 Feb 8am; I just want to read the files populated after 23 Feb 9am till 24 Feb 8am.

Also, Files just have last modified to identfy and nothing in the file name.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder inside the log folder say **Archive**. When file is read completely move the file to Archive folder using FileSystemTask. 
You can also create a folder like ErrorFeeds where move files if they did not get processed completely.

Comment: But, I dont have the priviledge/ Access to cut any file from source location. So, I need any solution where, I can keep last file with Last modified date. So that , next time..Somehow I may compare that time(Yesterday 8am) and fetch all files greater than that(Yesterday 9am till Today).

Comment: ok, so what you can do is after the file is processed successfully rename it by appending something like 'verified' to its name and configure foreach loop container to pick files which do not have that name.